# jquery adding columns based on database records

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sqlite

I have an sqlite table with these columns:
| date | weight | bmi | mood | etc.

I want a table on my html page to display like this on the html page:

```
<table>
    <caption></caption>
    <thead>
         <tr>
               <td>(empty cell over row headings)</td>
               Additional tH's as needed (this is where each date entry goes)
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr>
               <th scope="row">Weight</th>
               additional tD's as needed (this is where each weight entry goes matched with date in column heading)
         </tr>
         <tr>
               <th scope="row">BMI</th>
               additional tD's as needed (same as above)
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

so basically I'm flipping the rows and columns for display purposes. This is all so I can graph the table using jQuery Visualize plugin that goes out as the date progresses. As you can imagine, over time more entries will be made adding to the columns of the display table. Here is what I have been messing around with so far (not including the graphing scripts ). I've gotten myself totally confused and now I'm just a mess...
Any suggestions would be a big help. I think I'm running into problems when trying to insert data into a table that's also trying to insert itself. I'm probably going about this wrong I bet.
Thanks
Mike

```
function homeSuccess(tx, results) {
    // Gets initial count of records in table...
    var entries = results.rows.length;
    // Iterates over all the existing records...
    for (var i = 0; i < entries; ++i) {
        // The following element id's can be found in the div's within the table below, see element.innerHTML line...
        var element = document.getElementById('colDate');
        element.innerHTML += '<th scope="col">' + results.rows.item(i).timeStamp + '</th>';
        var element2 = document.getElementById('tdWeight');
        element2.innerHTML += '<td>' + results.rows.item(i).weight + '</td>';
        var element3 = document.getElementById('tdBmi');
        element3.innerHTML += '<td>' + results.rows.item(i).bmi + '</td>';
    };
    // 'screenView2 is a placeholder on the main html page...
    var element = document.getElementById('screenView2');
    element.innerHTML = '<br /><br /><h1>Data:</h1><br />Number of entries: ' + entries + '<br />' + '<table><caption>Mikes Health</caption><thead><tr><td></td><div id="colDate"></div></tr></thead><tbody><tr><th scope="row">Weight</th><div id="colWeight"></div></tr><tr><th scope="row">BMI</th><div id="colBmi"></div></tr></tbody></table>';

    // This section is just a test trying to plug in static elements prior to trying database data... When using this section I had the iteration section commented out.
    var element2 = document.getElementById('colDate');
    element2.innerHTML = '<th scope="col">4-1-13</th>';

    var element3 = document.getElementById('colWeight');
    element3.innerHTML = '<td scope="col">123</td>';

    var element4 = document.getElementById('colBmi');
    element4.innerHTML = '<td scope="col">321</td>';
}

function homeQuery(tx) {
    console.log("entering homeQuery");
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM HEALTHGRAPH', [], homeSuccess, onSqlError);
    console.log("leaving homeQuery");
}

// Function that is called on initial page load 
function homeDBopen() {
    console.log("opening db for home data");
    theDB = window.openDatabase("hgDB", "1.0", "HealthGraph", 3 * 1024 * 1024);
    theDB.transaction(homeQuery, onTxError, onTxSuccess);
    console.log("leaving homeDBopen");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought for sure someone would have answered this question as it seems like an issue lots of people must run into. A little discouraging. Anyway, I found an answer that I can adapt to my own project here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms532998(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms532998%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
// Insert cells into the header row.
  for (i=0; i<heading.length; i++)
  {
    oCell = oRow.insertCell(-1);... etc.
```